# changing state of one variable also changes another variable

Tags: android, arrays, list, flutter, dart

I'm writing a code for an app. I got stuck at a point and don't know what is the reason and solution. below is the code snippet.
[I assign variable of list as shown highlighted in picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Al1.png)

I am assigning this variable to listview. when i clear this "added" list "widget.serverData['items']" list also get clear. Can anyone help me out. Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `added` is `widget.serverData['items']` 
You can change from

```
added = widget.serverData['items'];
```

to

```
added = List.From(widget.serverData['items']);
```

For more info about reference sharing, please check out Binky Pointer Fun https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm5MNP7pn5g